# In R, how to plot 5x3 barplots from a x, y, z table?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I have a x by y by z table (see image below). I want to create 15 bar plots in one output arranged as 5 high and 3 across. For each bar plot, I want the x axis to be the labels "Caught", "Deterred" and "Successful", and the y axis to be the frequencies of "Caught", "Deterred" and "Successful". I would like the 5 bar plots high (not sure how to say this more clearly sorry) to represent the label of "Threshold" i.e. either 20, 40, 60, 80 or 90. I would like the 3 column bar plots across (again not sure how to say this properly so forgive me)  to represent the label "Model", i.e. either Model_1, Model_2 or Model_3. Thus, for example, the bar plot on row 1 column 1 (of the 5x3 bar plots), should be the "Caught", "Deterred", "Successful" frequencies for when I have Model_1 and Threshold of 20.

[image: The table I have]

Apologies for my poor explanation. Please let me know if anything needs clarifying. Thank you!

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `ggplot2` option that makes your "5 tall, 3 wide" simple with `facet`ing:

First, fake data:

```r
set.seed(42)
n <- 500
Models <- table(
  Threshold = sample(c(20, 40, 60, 80, 90), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  Outcome = sample(c("Caught", "Deferred", "Successful"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  Model = sample(c("Model_1", "Model_2", "Model_3"), size = n, replace = TRUE)
)
Models
# , , Model = Model_1
#          Outcome
# Threshold Caught Deferred Successful
#        20     14       15         14
#        40      7       10         15
#        60     16       13         12
#        80      7       11          4
#        90     16       10         10
# , , Model = Model_2
#          Outcome
# Threshold Caught Deferred Successful
#        20     14       11         15
#        40      5       12         10
#        60     11        8         13
#        80      7       15          6
#        90     12       13         11
# , , Model = Model_3
#          Outcome
# Threshold Caught Deferred Successful
#        20     14        7         10
#        40     14       13          9
#        60      6       12         13
#        80     20        4         12
#        90     10        8         11
```

One good thing about something created with `table` is that `as.data.frame` gives us something *easy* to work with for `ggplot2`'s "long data" preference:

```r
head(as.data.frame(Models))
#   Threshold  Outcome   Model Freq
# 1        20   Caught Model_1   14
# 2        40   Caught Model_1    7
# 3        60   Caught Model_1   16
# 4        80   Caught Model_1    7
# 5        90   Caught Model_1   16
# 6        20 Deferred Model_1   15
```

The plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(as.data.frame(Models), aes(Outcome, Freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(Threshold ~ Model)
```

[image: ggplot2 faceted barplot]

---

Note: if your data is naturally an `array` and not a `table`, we can easily accommodate that: `as.table(ary)` converts from an `array` to a `table` (which is really just an array underneath):

```r
set.seed(42)
ary <- array(sample(20, size=2*3*3, replace=TRUE), dim = c(2,3,3))
dimnames(ary) <- list(Threshold=c(20,40), Outcome=c("C","D","S"), Model=1:3)

ary
# , , Model = 1
#          Outcome
# Threshold  C  D  S
#        20 19  6 13
#        40 19 17 11
# , , Model = 2
#          Outcome
# Threshold  C  D  S
#        20 15 14 10
#        40  3 15 15
# , , Model = 3
#          Outcome
# Threshold  C  D  S
#        20 19 10 20
#        40  6 19  3

as.table(ary)
### same output as `ary`

head(as.data.frame(as.table(ary)))
#   Threshold Outcome Model Freq
# 1        20       C     1   19
# 2        40       C     1   19
# 3        20       D     1    6
# 4        40       D     1   17
# 5        20       S     1   13
# 6        40       S     1   11
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much for this! I really appreciate it very much. Have a great day!